# How to write the Custom Policy in wso2esb for simple username & passward

Tags: ws-security, wso2, wso2-esb

I wish to write custom policy .How would i start .
I couldn't find any blogs about that .
My issue is my client has been fixed header request for authentication.So The Username-token authentication scenario is perfect for me .But client unable to send the Proper format request as per the Scenario needed .
Its sending username password in some other format

```
<soapenv:Header>
          <pr:authentication soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:pr="http://webservices.im.com/ProxyService">
             <pr:user>mwp</pr:user>
             <pr:password>MWp003</pr:password>
          </pr:authentication>
       </soapenv:Header>
```

But its not working in wso2 ESB Username-token scenario.Expecting input Header is like this

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-4">
            <wsu:Created>2014-06-02T07:15:21Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2014-06-02T08:38:41Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
            <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">admin</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">byWKVY4stEATvTqaoNMswQ==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2014-06-02T07:15:21.304Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse: >
   </soapenv:Header
```

So what is the solution for this how would  achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ESB uses WS-Security specification to secure Web services. Therefore, client need to send messages according to that specification.  But in your case,  It seems to be your client sending user/password in custom SOAP headers. Then these can not be validated by ESB. There can be two solutions.

1. You need to modify your client to compliant with WS-Security spec.
2. You can write some custom handler (axis2 handler) to read custom headers in your message and validate user/password against the user store.
   Basically WS-Security messages are also validated by a axis2 handler called `Apache Rampart`.

Comment: i know the 2 solution validating username/pass against of user-store.But its again a extra call.So i wish to avoid it with default security.At last i came to know that wso2eb is not the Out of Box

Comment: It is not extra web service call.. Axis2 handler can directly use user store manager and verify the authentication.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay.Please will you edit your answer as per your suggestion or any blogs regarding that.But in which format it will take the message I mean xml elements.becoz i need to write as per client request

Comment: Please send brief explanation about this. You can write some custom handler (axis2 handler) to read custom headers in your message and validate user/password against the user store.